# How can we dynamically pass data to display the years (2008, 2009, 2010) titles in bubble chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

In the following bubble chart example:
      http://vallandingham.me/gates_bubbles/
Please click on 'Grant By years' tab

Can anybody help me out to pass the data dynamically to display the years(2008, 2009, 2010) tittle in the bubble chart? ''
The above example is using coffescript as i am very new to the script

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The data already determines the tooltip for the bubbles?

Comment: Sorry lars for the incomplete information. If you open the link(http://vallandingham.me/gates_bubbles/), and click 'Grants By Years' tab, the Years '2008', '2009', '2010' are displayed statically. My question here is how can we pass dynamic values to display the years title. assuming i have a dropdown containing values decads between 2000-2010, 1990-200 etc.

Comment: Oh I see. Well the years are defined in the script (`year_centers`), so you would need to change that.